# How to do list box in android

Tags: android, xml, listview, button

am trying to do .when i click a button opens another activity and shows list box. In that list box display a list of  values of particular column of table. that is we have to retrieve from 
sqlite database. 
how to do??

like this:

http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fimages%2Ftk-combobox.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fruby%2Fruby_tk_combobox.htm&docid=SVhMpjb5FMImxM&tbnid=l4yuDUmNF-lm5M&w=220&h=242&ei=HBNRUay8B8OUrgeA94CYDw&ved=0CAcQxiAwBQ&iact=ricl

Answer (score 2):

1. Fetch the results from database
2. Put it in a adapter
3. Populate android spinner with the adapter

Use the link below for reference
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to big so don't possible entire code i am just giving you guide line.

**Step:**

1. You have to fetch all record in database and store into `Collection` class variable.
2. Set those variable to `adapter`.
3. You have to used `onClick` and get information which is require.

You can refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) tutorial may be helpful.If this is helpful then accept answer.